# Как создать папки в просмотре проекта QtCreator

Tags: qtcreator

Проект разрастается и есть необходимость в размещение .c, .h, .ui в отдельные папки, для простоты работы.

Погуглил [нашел](http://www.prog.org.ru/topic_10017_0.html).

Сделал и получил ошибку:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target 'choicegraphwindow.ui', needed by 
'ui_choicegraphwindow.h'.  Stop.
```

Что делал:

1. Создал каталог choicegraphwindow
2. Добавил в каталог choicegraphwindow файлы choicegraphwindow.h , choicegraphwindow.cpp , choicegraphwindow.pri , choicegraphwindow.ui
3. В файл choicegraphwindow.pri давил:

   ```
   # -----------------------------------------------------------
   # operate objects
   # -----------------------------------------------------------
   # Header files
   HEADERS += choicegraphwindow.h

   # Source files
   SOURCES += choicegraphwindow.cpp

   # Form files
   FORMS += choicegraphwindow.ui
   ```
4. В файл .pro находящимся в корневой папки проекта добавил:

   ```
   #Include file(s)
   include(choicegraphwindow/choicegraphwindow.pri)
   ```

Удалил из .pro

```
    HEADERS += choicegraphwindow.h

    SOURCES += choicegraphwindow.cpp

    FORMS += choicegraphwindow.ui
```

После открыл проект выполнил qmake. При сборки получил ошибку.

Comment: Можно файлы в проект добавлять мышкой.

Comment: Надо сделать `HEADERS += $$PWD/choicegraphwindow.h` и т.д.

Comment: @Pavel Gridin Добавил HEADERS += $$PWD/choicegraphwindow.h Получил ошибку /home/alexey/project /menu_1.h:7: error: choicegraphwindow.h: No such file or directory
 #include <choicegraphwindow.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: Я понимаю что можно решить проблему вот так #include <choicegraphwindow/choicegraphwindow.h>. Но это очень не удобно править каждый раз инклуд.

Comment: @zhilenkov, надо тогда ещё добавить в pri-файл `INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD`

Comment: спасибо помогло